# SWIG -- How can I ignore a templated C++ function?

Tags: c++, templates, swig

I have a C++ class that resembles this:

```
namespace ns {
    template<class T>
    class Wrapper {
    public:
        bool operator==(const Wrapper<T>& rhs) const;  
        // Other methods
    private:
        T mData;
    };
}
```

I want to wrap this in SWIG/Python, but I don't want to include the equality operator. I have tried various things:

```
%ignore ns::Wrapper::operator==;
%ignore ns::Wrapper::operator==(const ns::Wrapper&) const;
```

And I've also gone through with class that T  might represent (let's say it's class Data for now):

```
%ignore ns::Wrapper<Data>::operator(const ns::Wrapper<Data>&) const;
%template(WrappedData) ns::Wrapper<Data>;
%ignore WrappedData::operator==(const WrappedData&) const;
```

Comment: BTW, reference is missing in your declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following `%ignore` directives, which must come **before the declaration** of the `Wrapper` class (e.g., before the corresponding `%include` directive):

- `%ignore ns::Wrapper::operator==;`
- `%ignore ns::Wrapper<Data>::operator==;`

Answer (score 1):

SWIG will automatically ignore operators that are not fully defined as part of a class. [(source)](http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/trac/src/swig-1.3.25/Doc/Manual/Python.html#Python_nn24). Redefining the equality operator as a non-member function worked.